# Convert categorical "other" value to NA in a data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, na

`trial <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "other"), c("a","b","Others","d"))`

There are 2 categorical variables (attributes) in the data frame. I want to recode the value "other" as NA. I follow the link here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/replace-with-na.html
[image]

```
na_strings <- c("other", "Others")
trial %>%
  replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% na_strings)
```

However, the "other" value does change to NA, but all other characters are turned into numbers. I want the rest of the values to remain character. 
What should i do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the `naniar` package, but I'm guessing you have `factors` in your `trial` which are causing issues. Does it work if you specify `trial <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "other"), c("a","b","Others","d"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(naniar)

trial %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>%
  replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% na_strings)
```

You just need to change your variable class from factor to character before the `replace_with_na_all` function.

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green check mark if it has solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base R :

```
trial[sapply(trial, `%in%`, na_strings)] <- NA
```

Or only `dplyr` to do this :

```
library(dplyr)
trial %>% mutate_all(~replace(., . %in% na_strings, NA))

#  col1 col2
#1    A    a
#2    B    b
#3    C <NA>
#4 <NA>    d
```

**data**

```
trial <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "other"), 
                    col2 = c("a","b","Others","d"))
```